# Django can't find static images in templates

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I've looked at pretty much all the examples here and in the documentation and it just isn't working at all

So in my **settings.py** file I have

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/mattr/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/mattr/public/'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ('django.core.context_processors.static',)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = ('mattr/public', )
```

Basically everything needed to handle static files.

In **urls.py** I have the normal patterns for pages (templates load just fine) and have this extra line

```
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

In **views.py** I have (this is for the homepage):

```
def home(request):
    t = get_template('index.html');
    html = t.render(RequestContext(request))
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

And in the template file **index.html** I have the line

```
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}media/images/Mattr1.png">
```

And yet it never shows images. Even when I try to just go to the image file directly at *http://127.0.0.1:8000/mattr/public/media/images/Mattr1.png* it gives me a Page Not Found error. 
I was a bit confused where the path starts from but because my template page loads I figured I had the paths correct

Comment: what url you are expecting if this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/mattr/public/media/images/Mattr1.png` is wrong? That will help to reconfigure your settings

Comment: @AamirAdnan Basically from my site's root (the location of manage.py) I have the file at "/mattr/public/images/Mattr1.png" so I expected it to show that

Comment: so then it should be like this `<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/Mattr1.png">`

Comment: @AamirAdnan Sorry, there was supposed to be a media in there also (in the file path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you're talking about static files, do this :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/' #or whatever you want

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/path/to/static/root/directory/',
)
```

Don't forget the coma or django's admin won't have its css.
It's done, no need to change anything in the `urls.py`

if you're talking about media, do this :

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/media/' # or whatever you want

MEDIA_URL = '/path/to/media/root/directory'
```

and place this at the bottom at `myproject.urls` :

```
import settings
urlpatterns += patterns('', url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,}),)
```

done!

Comment: **no need to change anything in the urls.py**
I had added static redirects to my url.py, which was preventing this from working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your settings.py:

```
import os
DIRNAME = os.path.dirname(__file__)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(DIRNAME, 'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

in your templates:

```
{{STATIC_URL}}css/etc...
```

You are also overwriting your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` instead do this:
in your settings.py

```
import django.conf.global_settings as DEFAULT_SETTINGS

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = DEFAULT_SETTINGS.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + (
"whatever_your_adding",
)
```

Comment: So that STATIC_ROOT line, where should I put my files then? It looks like it's adding an extra 'static' somewhere to the path

Also, the template line caused a syntax error because of the +

Answer (score 0):

Using '/' in front of the path denotes you are referring from root directory which I guess is not the case. Try doing this.

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'mattr/static/'
```