# Why is my static CSS not working in Django?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am having problem with my static CSS not working for my Django web app. I have followed the directions from the [Django Static Link tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) on handling static files, but it is still not working.

### Settings

```
# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = '/Users/a9austin/Development/sites/AlphaSocks/src/static_root/'

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
# Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
# Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
# Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
'/Users/a9austin/Development/sites/AlphaSocks/src/staticfiles'

)
```

### view

```
#from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response


def index(request):
return render_to_response('index.html')
```

### index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{STATIC_URL}}css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" >
```

And my directory organization is

> src->staticfiles->css->style.css

Comment: 'What' is not working? How do you render your views, using render() or render_to_response()? Is static files context processor turned on in settings.py?

Comment: Yes I am using render_to_response, I will update it with my view. It's not working by the css is not actually changing my html.

Comment: see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407383/django-cant-find-static-images-in-templates/13410225#13410225) to handle static files

Comment: @OtskimanotSqilal Thank you for the reply, I just updated it with my STATICFILES_DIR, my css is still not showing up.

Comment: The way you configured `STATICFILES_DIRS` and `STATIC_ROOT` is incorrect. They cannot contain the same directories. Please refer to my answer for more info.

Comment: django sucks. too much trouble

Answer (score 58, accepted):

For Django to serve static files, you have to make sure you have a couple of settings.

**STATIC_URL**

This setting specifies what URL should static files map to under. You have that done already.

**STATICFILES_DIRS**

This specifies all the folders on your system where Django should look for static files. The idea is that you might have a couple of apps within your project, and each app might require a different set of static files. So for organizational purposes, each app might contain a `static` directory where it will store only its static files. So then Django has to have a way to know where those directories are. This is what this setting is for.

**STATIC_ROOT**

This setting specifies where Django will copy all the static files to and not where the static files are already at. The idea is that once you leave development into production, Django can't serve static files anymore due to issues I will not go here (it's in the [article](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development)). However, for production, all static files should be in a single directory, instead of in many like specified in `STATICFILES_DIRS`. So this setting specifies a directory to which Django will copy all the static files from all files within `STATICFILES_DIRS` by running the following command:

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic
```

Please note this is only necessary once you go into production and also that the directory specified here cannot be the same as any directory specified in `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

**Urls.py**

In development for Django to serve your static files, you have to include the static URLs in your urls.py:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = ...

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

---

Once you will complete all of the above things, your static files should be served as long as you have `DEBUG = True`. Out of the list above, you seem to only complete `STATIC_URL`. Also please note that all the steps I described above are in the docs you linked in your question ([link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development)). It might be a bit confusing in the beginning but if you read it a couple of times, it becomes clearer.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Let me make sure I understand. So STATICFILES_DIR is actaully where the static files are. And STATIC_ROOT is where python will copy/handle them?

Comment: Yes, but it will only copy them by running the `manage.py` command and it is only necessary for production. In development Django will look and serve static files located in any of the directories in `STATICFILES_DIRS`. Also I forgot to mention, in the view make sure you use `RequestContext` to be able to use `{{ STATIC_URL }}`. The answer by Kavanaugh Development shows that.

Comment: Okay so when I called python manage.py collectstatic, it gives me an error. '"Your STATICFILES_DIRS setting is not a tuple or list; "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Your STATICFILES_DIRS setting is not a tuple or list; perhaps you forgot a trailing comma?' I updated my post to what I have changed my root and dir. Please take a look. Thank again for helping me out

Comment: Right. So your `STATICFILES_DIRS` is like `( 'string_here' )` which is not a tuple. Change that to `( 'string_here', )` which is a Python tuple.

Comment: But again, for development you don't have to collect all the static files. Django will serve them from `STATICFILES_DIRS` directories directly...

Answer (score 14):

Try clearing your cache. If you are using Google chrome go to your settings>clear browsing data> select clear cached images and files then click clear data

Answer (score 5):

For me it was changing

`<link rel="stylesheet" href=" {% static '/css/style.css' %} ">`

to

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" {% static '/css/style.css' %} ">`

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes all it takes is just "Ctrl + F5"

A Total refresh of the page, does the trick.

Or Ctrl + Shift + R

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30295459)

Comment: This solved the problem for me.

Comment: Am glad it did. Works every time for me

Comment: This is the same answer as Raghav Rathi's from March 26th and Joshua Blue- Jack's from February 3rd.

Answer (score 2):

After doing all, setting DEBUG= True, python collectstatic, clearing cache, opening in incognito mode if the problem still exists copy your .css file into another new .css file in static folder, and then run collectstatic command. This worked out for me. 
I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Adding RequestContext to the response should load the STATIC_URL variable into the template.

Try changing:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def index(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html')
```

to:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template.context import RequestContext

def index(request):
    return render_to_response("index.html", context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Refer to the Django Documentation on  [Referring to static files in templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#referring-to-static-files-in-templates) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no problem in coding and no errors shown.
Then you can do this this to try to solve the problem.

**Clear your Cache:**

If you are using Google chrome go to your settings --> clear browsing data -->
select clear cached images and files then click clear data

Comment: This is the same answer as Joshua Blue- Jack's from February 3rd.

Answer (score 0):

If this is happening to you in development mode, make sure you set `DEBUG=True` in your `settings.py` file. Also make sure that the `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` are set in your `settings.py` file like so :

```
MEDIA_URL  = '/mymediafolder/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mymediafolder')
```

And then in your main urls file `myapp/urls.py` you must have the following :

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    #Your url patterns here
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The `staticfiles_urlpatterns()` is used to serve static files in development mode.

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete my staticfiles folder.  It seemed like there was a similarly named file in it which was being read from or written to and this wasn't the one my app was pulling from for the site.  After I ran 'collectstatic' again, it re-added the staticfiles folder and contents and is now working and updating properly.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me except these

I set these in project settings.

```
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

And then in the url file I did this

```
    from django.urls import re_path
    from django.views.static import serve
    
    urlpatterns = [
        re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
        re_path(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
    ]
```

Answer (score -1):

My solution may be silly, but maybe it will help someone. If you copy the line from the internet instead of typing it, make sure to adjust your quotation marks. Worked for me.

```
<link rel=”stylesheet” type="text/css" href="{% static 'styles.css' %}">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'styles.css' %}">
```

Answer (score -5):

There is an easy way if you feel that your CSS isn't working.
If your project isn't way too huge then you can just make
the CSS file in the same file as the HTML.
And then run it.That way it will run for example

`

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Promantus Bot</title>
      <style type="text/css"> 
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color:#FF625F;
}

h1, p {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: #323330;
    font-size:  100px;
}


p {
    font-size: 30px;
}

#output, #container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 100px;
}


input {
    background-color: #eee;
    border: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 30px;
}






</style>


</head>

<body>

  <div id="output"></div>

<div id="container">
    <input type="text" id="input" value="">
</div>





</body>

</html>
`
It's going to run fine this way.
```

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked.