# Static files are not loaded in a Django website hosted on Bluehost

Tags: python, django, static, fastcgi, bluehost

as you can see it live on the website: http://www.workshopvenues.com
the **static** files that are under /assets/* are not loaded correctly.

I expect this url (for example) to be valid: http://www.workshopvenues.com/assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png
but it's not (as you can verify clicking on it).

This is what I have in my **settings.py**

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home6/ptlugorg/workshopvenues/workshopvenues/workshopvenues/assets/'

STATIC_URL = 'http://www.workshopvenues.com/assets/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/home6/ptlugorg/workshopvenues/workshopvenues/workshopvenues/assets/',
)
```

The paths are correct, I've double checked them:

```
ptlugorg@ptlug.org [~/workshopvenues/workshopvenues/workshopvenues/assets]# pwd
/home6/ptlugorg/workshopvenues/workshopvenues/workshopvenues/assets
```

if it may help, I'm serving the website using fastcgi. I've followed the instructions here http://simplyargh.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/python-27-django-14-on-bluehost.html

and these are my configuration files.

**.htaccess**

```
ptlugorg@ptlug.org [~/public_html/workshopvenues]# cat .htaccess 
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ workshopvenues.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

**workshopvenues.fcgi**

```
ptlugorg@ptlug.org [~/public_html/workshopvenues]# cat workshopvenues.fcgi 
#!/home6/ptlugorg/python27/bin/python27
import sys, os

# Add a custom Python path.
sys.path.insert(0, "/home6/ptlugorg/python27")
sys.path.insert(13, "/home6/ptlugorg/workshopvenues/workshopvenues")

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'workshopvenues.settings'
from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

Just in case you are wondering about the **permissions**:

```
ptlugorg@ptlug.org [~/workshopvenues/workshopvenues/workshopvenues]# ls -al
total 52
drwxr-xr-x  3 ptlugorg ptlugorg 4096 Aug  9 03:31 ./
drwxr-xr-x  4 ptlugorg ptlugorg 4096 Aug  9 02:52 ../
drwxr-xr-x 11 ptlugorg ptlugorg 4096 Aug  8 15:33 assets/
-rw-r--r--  1 ptlugorg ptlugorg    0 Aug  8 14:23 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--  1 ptlugorg ptlugorg  144 Aug  8 14:25 __init__.pyc
-rw-r--r--  1 ptlugorg ptlugorg  430 Aug  8 15:20 secrets.py
-rw-r--r--  1 ptlugorg ptlugorg  527 Aug  8 15:20 secrets.pyc
-rw-r--r--  1 ptlugorg ptlugorg 5779 Aug  9 03:31 settings.py
-rw-r--r--  1 ptlugorg ptlugorg 3399 Aug  9 03:31 settings.pyc
-rw-r--r--  1 ptlugorg ptlugorg  614 Aug  8 14:23 urls.py
-rw-r--r--  1 ptlugorg ptlugorg  467 Aug  8 15:23 urls.pyc
-rw-r--r--  1 ptlugorg ptlugorg 1150 Aug  8 14:23 wsgi.py
-rw-r--r--  1 ptlugorg ptlugorg 1058 Aug  8 15:21 wsgi.pyc

ptlugorg@ptlug.org [~/workshopvenues/workshopvenues/workshopvenues/assets]# ls -al
total 48
drwxr-xr-x 11 ptlugorg ptlugorg 4096 Aug  8 15:33 ./
drwxr-xr-x  3 ptlugorg ptlugorg 4096 Aug  9 03:31 ../
drwxr-xr-x  5 ptlugorg ptlugorg 4096 Aug  8 15:33 admin/
drwxr-xr-x  5 ptlugorg ptlugorg 4096 Aug  8 14:23 bootstrap/
drwxr-xr-x  2 ptlugorg ptlugorg 4096 Aug  8 14:23 css/
drwxr-xr-x  5 ptlugorg ptlugorg 4096 Aug  8 15:33 django_extensions/
drwxr-xr-x  2 ptlugorg ptlugorg 4096 Aug  8 14:23 font-awesome/
drwxr-xr-x  2 ptlugorg ptlugorg 4096 Aug  8 14:23 ico/
drwxr-xr-x  7 ptlugorg ptlugorg 4096 Aug  8 14:23 img/
drwxr-xr-x  2 ptlugorg ptlugorg 4096 Aug  8 14:23 js/
drwxr-xr-x  5 ptlugorg ptlugorg 4096 Aug  8 14:23 prettyPhoto/
```

Everything seems correct, but it still doesn't work as expected. Do you have any idea of where the problem could be? What tests I could do to verify if something is wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you set django to be in debug mode will the files be served through django? If this is the case then it means that your webserver is failing to server the static content.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to a kind user in **#django** (Freenode IRC channel) named **mattmcc**, I've been able to fix it. Actually it was a problem in the **STATIC_ROOT**. It was pointing to the phisical file location instead of pointing to the **DOCUMENT ROOT location**.

The correct **settings.py** is like this:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home6/ptlugorg/public_html/workshopvenues/assets/'

STATIC_URL = '/assets/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/home6/ptlugorg/workshopvenues/workshopvenues/workshopvenues/assets/',
)
```

Everything works now :)

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of clarity:

- `STATIC_ROOT` (The directory into which all of your static files across all apps are placed) *needs* to be within your `public_html/yoursite` folder in order to work.

Answer (score 0):

check this answer, [Django: CSS Is not not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446325/django-css-is-not-not-working), it seems that you have to run python manage.py collectstatic and also add some lines into your urls.py